# Using Confluence REST API to create a table that sorts

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I can create simple tables in Confluence using their existing API.  It works great.  This might be asking a lot, but one thing it doesn't do is sort like tables that are created in Confluence through the wysiwyg editor.

For example, I copy the HTML for a table from a hand-made Confluence document, and then create a new document using their api.  I stick this html into the document:

```
    myHtml = '
    <div class="table-wrap">
        <table class="confluenceTable tablesorter tablesorter-default stickyTableHeaders" style="padding: 0px;">
            <thead class="tableFloatingHeaderOriginal">
                <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader tablesorter-headerAsc" data-column="0" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">testcol</div></th>
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader" data-column="1" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader" data-column="2" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead class="tableFloatingHeader" style="display: none;">
                <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader" data-column="0" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">testcol</div></th>
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader" data-column="1" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
                    <th class="confluenceTh sortableHeader" data-column="2" tabindex="0" unselectable="on"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">q</td>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">r</td>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="confluenceTd">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    '
```

Then, using `curl` to `POST`:

```
curl -u username:password -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","ancestors":[{"type":"page","id":6358857}],"title":"new page 4","space":{"key":"~theuser"},"body":{"storage":{"value":myHtml,"representation":"storage"}}}' https://confluence.macsales.com/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

Everything looks great, except the table will not sort.  I did notice some of the tags like 'data-column="2"' were stripped from the HTML.  Is there a way to not strip these tags?

I saw another posts that suggests using Confluence CLI instead, but this technique is working just fine so far.  It would just be nice to be able to sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a silly mistake on my part.  I was copying the html that was generated post-rendering instead of the html source.  By using Confluence's classes, sorting works:

```
<table class="confluenceTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="confluenceTh">test321</th>
            <th class="confluenceTh"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="confluenceTd">h</td>
            <td class="confluenceTd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="confluenceTd">k</td>
            <td class="confluenceTd"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```